# SQL query is only displaying the column in 'where clause'

Tags: php, mysql, database, search, bootstrap-4

I have a website where it shows restaurant information. I am fetching it through database and I am using php.

When I search for anything it does shows the result in my website. But, for example if there is one `div` that contains the data of restaurant such as phono no, name, address etc and I searched for the restaurant name, it will only show the restaurant name but hide rest of the information and if it matches (the name) somewhere else let's say in reviews it will show that but again hides the rest. In short only shows that specific words. How can I make it show the full div in my case `myDiv` so the user can see rest of the information as well. If they search for the name of restaurant it's obvious they would want to see that restaurant information (which is in the div) rather hiding it and only showing the matches only. Sorry for long explanation just making sure it's understandable what I am trying to say. If any more information is needed please leave me a comment.

My code:

```
      echo '<input class="form-control" id="searchAnything" type="text" placeholder="Search..">';

while ($result = $getRestaurantData->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
    //restaurant id
    echo "<div class='container' id='myDIV'>";

    //getting basicinfo data by _id
    echo "<div class='row'>";
    echo "<div class='col-sm'>";
    getInfo($result['_id']);
    echo "</div>";
    //getting highlights data by _id
    echo "<div class='col-sm'>";
    echo "<nav>";
    echo " <div class='nav nav-tabs' id='nav-tab' role='tablist'>";
    echo "<a class='nav-link active' id='nav-highlights-tab' data-toggle='tab' href='#nav-highlights' role='tab' aria-controls='nav-highlights' aria-selected='true'>Highlights</a>";
    echo "<a class='nav-link' id='nav-review-tab' data-toggle='tab' href='#nav-reviews' role='tab' aria-controls='nav-reviews' aria-selected='false'>Reviews</a>";
    echo "</div>";
    echo "</nav>";
    echo "<div class='tab-content' id='nav-tabContent'>";
    echo "<div class='tab-pane fade show active' id='nav-highlights' role='tabpanel' aria-labelledby='nav-highlights-tab'>" .
    getData1($result['_id']) .

        "</div>";
    echo "<div class='tab-pane fade' id='nav-reviews' role='tabpanel' aria-labelledby='nav-reviews-tab'>" .
    getData2($result['_id']) .
        "</div>";

    echo "</div>";
    echo "</div>";
    echo "</div>";
    echo "</div>";

}


echo "<script>
console.log('yoo');


$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#searchAnything').on('keyup', function () {
      var value = $(this).val().toLowerCase();
      $('#myDIV *').filter(function () {
        $(this).toggle($(this).text().toLowerCase().indexOf(value) > -1)
      });
    });
  });

</script>";
```

Updated code (try to change to html before it was php):

```
 <input class="form-control" id="searchAnything" type="text" placeholder="Search..">';
    
        while ($result = $getRestaurantData->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
            //restaurant id
            <div class='container' id='myDIV'>
        
            //getting basicinfo data by _id
           <div class='row'>
            <div class='col-sm'>
            getInfo($result['_id'];
            </div>
            //getting highlights data by _id
            <div class='col-sm'>
            <nav>
             <div class='nav nav-tabs' id='nav-tab' role='tablist'>
            <a class='nav-link active' id='nav-highlights-tab' data-toggle='tab' href='#nav-highlights' role='tab' aria-controls='nav-highlights' aria-selected='true'>Highlights</a>";
            echo "<a class='nav-link' id='nav-review-tab' data-toggle='tab' href='#nav-reviews' role='tab' aria-controls='nav-reviews' aria-selected='false'>Reviews</a>
            </div>
            </nav>
           <div class='tab-content' id='nav-tabContent'>
            <div class='tab-pane fade show active' id='nav-highlights' role='tabpanel' aria-labelledby='nav-highlights-tab'>" .
            getData1($result['_id']) .
        
                </div>
            <div class='tab-pane fade' id='nav-reviews' role='tabpanel' aria-labelledby='nav-reviews-tab'>" .
            getData2($result['_id']) .
                </div>
             </div>
            </div>
            </div>
            </div>
        
        }
        
        
        
        <script>
        
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $('#searchAnything').on('keyup', function () {
              var value = $(this).val().toLowerCase();
              $('#myDIV *').filter(function () {
                $(this).toggle($(this).text().toLowerCase().indexOf(value) > -1)
              });
            });
          });
        
        </script>
    
    function getRestaurantHighlights($restaurant_id)
    {
    <h2>Resturant name</h2>
    <p>info</p>
    <h2>info 2</h2>
    <p>phone no</p>
    }
    
    
    function getRestaurantReviews($restaurant_id)
    {
    <h2>Reviews</h2>
    }
```

Comment: Your problem is with the JavaScript part of this, so please show an example of the generated HTML, instead of the (currently irrelevant) PHP code. This will make it much easier for people to test your code (no one of us here has your database setup available, so that we could actually run your PHP code and get any meaningful result.)

Comment: @04FS I will update my code soon and add HTML rather php

Comment: Please have a look. I try my best to change my code to HTML so you guys can get some idea of what I’m doing and added some functions and data that I’m using in my code (I’m fetching through database but here I have given an example) and I do have header and paragraph tags in the function in my actual code except data is different (but it doesn’t matter here) hope that helps.

Comment: That is still PHP code. Please copy&paste the relevant parts from the source code view of your page in the browser.

Comment: Incidentally, to my mind, sticking "echo" at the start of every line does nothing for readability

Comment: @04FS unfortunately it’s a lot of code in HTML if I try to copy from the website and most of it makes no sense and all the code is not formatted at all. And I have a lot of data so it would take me days to format the code. I’m not sure how else I can help.

Comment: You could for example modify your loop, so that it outputs only the first three or four items. Or you use an editor with syntax highlighting and formatting capabilities, and then remove excess items there.